# Automatic white space insertion?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a side project that I am working on on learning php and sql, mixed with some ajax.  I have the following code(samples) that inserts specific data into a database :

index.php -

```
<textarea class="form-control txt" rows='3' name="data[Address]" id="Address" placeholder="Your Address">
                        <?php echo isset($results['data']['Address']) ? str_replace("<br />","\n", $results['data']['Address']): ''; ?></textarea>
```

functions.php -

```
$data['data']['Address'] = str_replace("\n","<br />", $data['data']['Address']);
```

sql data -

```
if($id!=NULL && !empty($id)){
$query = "UPDATE test SET address = '$data' WHERE id = $id";}
```

Here is my question.  Data saves fine into the database, and I can read it back from index.php, but when I go to RE-save it, it adds whitespace before the address field(3 tabs worth), so that when I go to read the data again through index.php, it does not show.

How can I get it to NOT save whitespace, or to remove unneeded whitespace?

Comment: look into [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) also look into [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) you should save the raw input from the user in the db and when displaying not in a textarea, you use the nl2br option.

Comment: I suspect you have extra whitespace between `<textarea>` and `<?php echo` in the form.

Comment: @Barmar Brilliant Idea, had to check to make sure, but no go, ill update the code to show what it looks like....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're storing the contents from the Textarea as HTML in Database. You should always store the "real data" from your $_POST to database. (So newlines stay newlines in your database). The escaping will happen just before you send the data to the browser using htmlspecialchars() or htmlentities().

For your concrete problem try following: Output your POST form-data directly into your textarea:

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <textarea name="input"><?= htmlspecialchars ($_POST["input"]); ?></textarea>
    <button name="submit1" type="submit">Send it</button>
</form>
```

Your input-data should appear as you typed it. So use htmlspecialchars() instead of random trim()'ing or nl2br()'ing.

Additionally: Be carefull when building your SQL-Query. Make sure to proper escape each user-editable variable before adding it to the statement. See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Do it this way:

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO xyz ('val') VALUE ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["input"]). "')");
```

Or - even better: Make yourself familiar with some modern and much more secure way of database accessing - like using PDO ( http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php )

Comment: Thank you for noting the escapes(for security).  I would try the htmlspecialchars, but do not know if that would would work with the ajax script that this is parsing through.  I did try the trim statement in functions.php, and it lets me pull up the data now every time(didnt before) but still adds the whitespace on the initial save?  still looking into it, gotta love debugging :D

Comment: htmlspecialchars() will work with ajax - htmlentities() won't under some circumstances ;-) - Please post the full code from <textarea> till </textare>. Maybe you have spaces in between? PHP won't add spaces anywhere by itself.